# Sending data through TCP socket not working. Error: No Error

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, socketserver

I am writing a client-server c++ program where a user-specified number of clients (ESP32 boards) communicate with a server by sending sniffed packets. For semplicity let's assume only 1 client. After establishing a connection, the client sends the server all the packets sniffed in a fragmented way so that for each packet the various fields such as length, MAC, etc. are sent. The problem is that in most of the times the communication fails since the server is unable to read a certain field. Also debugging I noticed that the client has no sending problems and stops writing packets only when the server, on the other side, shuts down the connection because it has failed to read a field. What can be the problem?

Client send code (only few fields):

```
    // sending packet length
    cwrite = connection->doSend((const char*)(&packet_length), sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
    if (cwrite != sizeof(uint32_t)) {
        printf("Error sending packet length\n");
        std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << " with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // sending timestamp
    cwrite = connection->doSend((const char*)(&ts), sizeof(uint64_t), 0);
    if (cwrite != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        printf("Error sending timestamp\n");
        std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << " with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // sending channel
    cwrite = connection->doSend((const char*)(&chan), sizeof(uint8_t), 0);
    if (cwrite != sizeof(uint8_t)) {
        printf("Error sending channel\n");
        std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << " with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

where the doSend is simply:

```
ssize_t TCPConnect::doSend(const char* buff, int length, int flags){
    if(!isEnabled){
        std::cout << "Can't send, connection not enabled because " << errorEnable << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(!isConnected){
        std::cout << "Can't send, not connected because " << errorConnected << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return send(socket, buff, length, 0);
}
```

Server recv code (only some fields):

```
        // receive packet length
        char pl[4];
        cwrite = recv(s, pl, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
        if (cwrite != sizeof(uint32_t)) {
            printf("Error receving packet length\n");
            std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << ", with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        // receiving timestamp
        char ts[8];
        cwrite = recv(s, ts, sizeof(uint64_t), 0);
        if (cwrite != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
            printf("Error receving timestamp\n");
            std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << ", with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        // receiving channel
        char chan;
        cwrite = recv(s, &chan, sizeof(uint8_t), 0);
        if (cwrite != sizeof(uint8_t)) {
            printf("Error receiving channel\n");
            std::cout << "Cwrite is " << cwrite << "with error " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

[The image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6Gh.png)

Comment: In a TCP stream, you're not guaranteed to receive exactly the number of bytes you ask for. That is, you may ask to `recv` 8 bytes, but you might actually receive only 6 (due to buffering effects on both systems' kernels). That's *not* a bug or error condition. You should just keep calling `recv` until you get an error (-1), EOF (0) or you have all the bytes you expect to receive. TCP does *not* preserve message boundaries; your application is responsible for maintaining those. (Likewise, though less commonly an issue, `send` doesn't guarantee to deliver all bytes either.)

Comment: Thank you so much. In that case i'll use a simple while condition to read / send all bytes i need.